# Adding Elements to List using For Loop in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, append

I am trying to create a simple data frame that contains information about what authors and their respective papers. I have a matrix that contains the author IDs as the rows and the paper IDs as the columns. This matrix contains 1s and 0s, where a 1 indicates that the author worked on that paper. For example, if A2P[1,1] == 1, that means that the author with ID 1 worked on the paper with ID 1.

I am trying to convert this matrix into a simple data frame that contains all of these relationships, something that just contains the author IDs and the papers that they worked on. As in,

```
au_ID  P_ID
1      1
1      12        # Author 1 has worked on both paper 1 and 12
2      1         # Author 2 has also worked on paper 1, in addition to papers 2 and 3. 
2      2
2      3 
...
```

Here is what I am doing:

```
list1 <- list()
list2 <- list()
# Rows are Author IDs
# Columns are Paper IDs
for (row in 1:nrow(A2P)){
  for (col in 1:ncol(A2P)){
    if (A2P[row,col] == 1){
      list1 <- append(list1, row)
      list2 <- append(list2, col)
    }
  }
}
authorship["au_ID"] = list1
authorship["P_ID"] = list2
```

I am having difficulty getting this code to run quickly. It is taking forever to run, going on twenty minutes now. I think it has something to do with appending each row and column value to each of the lists, but I am unsure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely need `which(A2P == 1L, arr.ind = TRUE)`

```
mat <- matrix(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), ncol = 3)

mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    1
#[2,]    0    1    0
#[3,]    0    1    1

which(mat == 1L, arr.ind = TRUE)
#     row col
#[1,]   1   1
#[2,]   2   2
#[3,]   3   2
#[4,]   1   3
#[5,]   3   3
```

In this case, `row` would correspond to `au_ID` and `col` would correspond to `P_ID`. Then to get it in your format completely:

```
authorship <- which(mat == 1L, arr.ind = TRUE)
colnames(authorship) <- c('au_ID', 'P_ID')

as.data.frame(authorship)
##  au_ID P_ID
##1     1    1
##2     2    2
##3     3    2
##4     1    3
##5     3    3
```

Comment: Nice solution, love the simplicity

Comment: Thank you very much! My code actually did finish running, and I was able to create the data frame I wanted using the following: ```authorship <- do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, au_ID=list1, P_ID=list2))```

Comment: However, yours is so much more compact and does not use a loop. Thank you very much! I really appreciate it as I'm quite new to R - I was trying to use python syntax with the whole ```authorship["au_ID"]``` thing.